# Bracket and dot notation in compiled CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have this piece of code in a Node/Express app:

```
app.use "/static", express.directory("#{__dirname}/public")
app.use "/static", express.static("#{__dirname}/public")
```

It compiles to this:

```
app.use("/static", express.directory("" + __dirname + "/public"));
app.use("/static", express["static"]("" + __dirname + "/public"));
```

By curiosity, I am wondering: why is the dot notation used for the first call and the bracket notation for the second call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `static` is reserved in ES3. (not anymore in ES5).

Answer (score 3):

Because static is a reserved word in Javascript prior to EcmaScript 5 .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Some browsers might throw an error if it is used as an object property with the `object.word` syntax .

`object['word']` ensure no error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

`static` is a reserved word (reserved for future use as a keyword) in javascript.

You can see a list of reserved words here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

For example, `x.in` compiles to `x["in"]`, because `in` is also a reserved word.